# How to flag a post which contains both answer and a new question

Tags: support, flags

I recently encountered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180097/2254048). The user has answered the problem asked by the OP but he asked his own question in the same post. Uploaded the picture as if the flag is accepted then answer will be removed.

[image]

**How should I flag such posts in future?**

**PS:** For the moment, I flagged it as "Require Moderator Attention" with a custom message explaining the situation.

Comment: I guess being over 2K you could edit this to a minimal answer, remove the noise, and post a comment explaining what you did so the user who posted this is aware of the proper way to behave on Stack?

Comment: @Patrice Seems fair to me. **Lets see what community has to say.** Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Agreed with Patrice, no need for a mod. Also, the post should be closed but, after [Shog's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763691/programming-riddle-how-might-you-translate-an-excel-column-name-to-a-number/33180097#comment575592_763691) , I'm hesitant. Though, his comment *was* 6 years ago

Comment: @Patrice - Even easier. It was an old question that was converted to community wiki, and all the answers are CW as well.

Comment: Codegolf.SE would write this in 12 letters :(  Oops, 11.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The post in question is community wiki, so I edited it to remove everything that wasn't part of the answer.  I also left the following comment for the OP:

> Thanks for the contribution. I removed the new question from this answer. If you want to ask a new question, please open a new question.

If anyone wants to improve the answer, have at it.

The question has a ton of answers and should probably still get the 'This post already has many good answers...' protection, but that's not my decision to make.

Comment: I approve of your handling of the post, and as there are already 27 visible and 4 deleted answers, I've gone ahead and protected it.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I approve of your protecting of the question. :)